# Excel VBA Listbox - Only Format non blanks as Dates

Tags: date, excel, listbox, formatting, vba

This one has me stumped. I am populating a Listbox with a range and then formatting column 4 as d/mm/yyyy. This works fine if *all* cells in column 4 have a date. As some cells that are populated into the Listbox are in fact blank the sub crashes when it hits these cells. I have tried various if and else statements to skip the activecell if blank with no luck.

Grateful for any assistance. 
Alex V

```
 Sub populate_listbox_1()

 Dim I As Long
 Dim I2 As Long
 Dim list_count As Long

Dim MyData As Range
    Dim r As Long
    With edit_report_input.compliments_listbox
        .ColumnCount = 17
        .ColumnWidths = "70;300;75;90;80;80;100;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;20;0"
        .RowSource = ""
        Set MyData = ActiveSheet.Range("A4:Q498")   'Adjust the range accordingly
        .List = MyData.Cells.Value
        For r = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If .List(r, 1) = "" Then
                .RemoveItem r
            End If
        Next r
    End With


For I = 0 To edit_report_input.compliments_listbox.ListCount - 1

       edit_report_input.compliments_listbox.List(I, 4) = Format(DateValue(edit_report_input.compliments_listbox.List(I, 4)), "d/mm/yyyy")

Next I

date_rec_compliment = Format(date_rec_compliment, "d/mm/yyyy")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can always check before changing the format. See if below snippet helps

```
For I = 0 To edit_report_input.compliments_listbox.ListCount - 1
   if edit_report_input.compliments_listbox.List(I, 4) <> "" Then
       edit_report_input.compliments_listbox.List(I, 4) = Format(DateValue(edit_report_input.compliments_listbox.List(I, 4)), "d/mm/yyyy")
   End If
Next I
```